# Active Record discrepancy between browser and console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a typical model setup with a `Parent` model which has many `Images`. `Image` belongs_to `Parent`.

`Image` has a `caption` column.

I have a view where I do a standard for each loop through the `Parent` model and I want to pull a random `Image` out like so:

```
<% @parent.each.with_index do |nut, index| %>
<h4><%= parent.name %></h4>
<p><%= parent.images.limit(1).order("RANDOM()").first.caption %></p>
<% end %>
```

In the console it works fine.  In the view it throws `undefined method "caption" for nil:NilClass`

At first I had added this to the `Parent` model as:

```
  def random_caption

    self.images.limit(1).order("RANDOM()").first

  end
```

and used:

```
<%= parent.random_caption.caption %>
```

and even:

```
<%= parent.images.first.caption %>
```

which nets the same error.  I am thinking I am missing some weird nuance of Active Record or something less obvious.

**EDIT**

Also weird - change to:

```
<%= parent.images.first %>
```

and in the view I get `#<Image:0x007fd8f7404430>` rendered so it looks like there is a record there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be some parent record which don't have any Images for that. That's why you are getting error.
Below line will not give any error till `parent.images.limit(1).order("RANDOM()")` you have record or not. It will return either array of object or `[]`. So better you check condition for blank images before this random.

```
parent.images.limit(1).order("RANDOM()").first.caption
```

So try change your code like this:

```
<% @parent.each.with_index do |parent, index| %>
  <h4><%= parent.name %></h4>
  <% if parent.images.present? %>
    <p><%= parent.images.limit(1).order("RANDOM()").first.caption %></p>
  <% else%>
    <p>No image there</p>
  <%end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you... That is super obvious now that you explained that. I was focused on the row that had an image and forgot about the empty ones. I need to update my original @parents search to ensure its ones with images.

Answer (score 0):

In your database do you have any images for that parent?

Comment: 2.0.0-p247 :008 > parent.first.caption
  Image Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images”.”parent_id" = $1  ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1  [[“parent_id", 1]]
 => “Front View”

Comment: I do... as noted the console spits out the expected results.